# Preventing duplicates from being added to shopping list DOM Selectors (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been attempting to prevent duplicate items from being added to a shopping list I created. I thought the code directly below might do it, but it hasn't been helping. I expected the JS code to access the ul tag and iterate through it's list items so it can compare what's already in the list to what's trying to be added. I'm assuming my issue is with accessing the input. Also, which function should this be done in? The createListElement function or the addListAfterClick function. Please see the code snippet for how the code runs. Thank you in advance!!

```
var ul = document.getElementById("shoppingcart");
      var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (input.value === items[i]); {
          alert("already in list");
          console.log("already in list");


        }
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length; // gets the length of the input value 

}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li"); // creating a new li tag
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); // adding input value to newly created li tag
  li.classList.add("item"); // adds a class called "item" to the newly created li tag
  li.addEventListener("click", toggleDone);
  /*  adds click abilities to new item by referencing the toggleDone function, this allows for a line-through 
                                               an item in the list if it's clicked,and will remove the line if the item is clicked again */

  ul.appendChild(li); // adds the li tag in the ul tag
  input.value = ""; //clears the input box to allow for new inputs 


  var button = document.createElement("button"); // creates anew button tag 
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete")); // creates a new button with the word "delete" 
  li.append(button); //adds delete button next to each new input in the shopping list 
  button.onclick = removeParent; // if the delete button is clicked, it references the removeParent function which deletes the an input from the shopping list
}

function removeParent(event) {
  event.target.parentNode.remove(); // simply deletes an input from the parent node, which is the ul tag, remember li tags are children of ul tags 
}

function toggleDone() {
  this.classList.toggle('done'); // references the css ".done" class, which allows for line-through text, the toggle function turns on and off the line through
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) //if the length of the input is greater than 0..(meaning you have to input a something in order to add to the list)
  {
    createListElement(); // references createListElement function, which adds a new li tag with the input value and a delete button next to it 

  }

}

function addListAfterKeyPress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) // if length of the input is greater than 0 and your press the enter key (13 is the value that represents the enter key)
  {
    {
      createListElement(); // references createListElement function, which adds a new li tag with the input value and a delete button next to it 
    }

  }

}


button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick); 
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeyPress);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> JavaScript + DOM </title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1> Shopping List</h1>
  <p id="first"> Get it done today</p>
  <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
  <button id="enter">Click Me!</button>

  <ul class="list" id="shoppingcart">
    <li class="bold red" random="23"> Notebook</li>

  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet does not run, as "test" is not defined: `input.addEventListener("keypress", test);`. Also "Section12.js" and "Section12.css" do not exist.

Comment: @terrymorse sorry I didn't catch that earlier, thank you. I've updated the code to reflect the changes. If you click on "Expand snippet"  to the right, you should be redirected to the html page.

Comment: Errors in the snippet persist. No `test`, no `Section12.js`.

Comment: @terrymorse It should be working fine now, let me know otherwise. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to use a "[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)", you can check the duplicity in simple steps. For example:

```js
var mySet = new Set();
mySet.add("foo");
mySet.add("fuu");
mySet.has("foo"); // true
mySet.has("fuu"); // true
mySet.has("faa"); // false
```

So, you can add a set in your first lines and set the conditional `has` in `addListAfterClick`:

```js
function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && !mySet.has(input.value))
  {
    createListElement();
  }

}
```

And `add` the value when input is done in `createListElement`:

```js
function createListElement()
{
  // code...
  ul.appendChild(li);
  mySet.add(input.value);
  input.value = "";
  // code...
}
```